# Always show bookmark in homepage, not while browsing - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I need to see the bookmark bar while in a [custom homepage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ichrome-your-homepage-for/oghkljobbhapacbahlneolfclkniiami?hl=en) (not default homepage), but want it hidden while browsing.

I know it can be done and undone by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> repeatedly, but I would like it to happen automatically. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: That's something your custom homepage developer would have to add AFAIK -- the homepage would have to make, itself, a bookmark bar and you would disable the normal one permanently.